# Can I call indexOf within a D3 selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a bar graph using D3 which uses an array of numbers `dataset[]` to generate and set the height of the bars.

I have a portion of code which generates a tooltip upon mouseover of a bar element.

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
    .select("#share-value")
    .text(d)
    .select("#month-now")
    .text(dataset.indexOf(d));
console.log(dataset.indexOf(d));
```

`text(d)` displays correctly, which is the value of `dataset[d]`. However, I would also like to display the index of the element `d` in `dataset`. `console.log(dataset.indexOf(d))` logs the index correctly but the index is not being displayed in the tooltip. Why is this so?

Edit: I have also tried

```
.text(function (d, i) {
        return i;
    });
```

according to [D3 Selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections), but it still does not seem to return the index of the current datum.

Comment: what is your dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of mouseover listener will give you the index of d.

```
.on("mouseover",function(d,i){ //i is the index of d in the dataset
   d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
    .select("#share-value")
    .text(d)
    .select("#month-now")
    .text(i);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming your dataset is an array of objects.
So you should be using something like this:

```
//imagine your dataset like this:
var dataset = [{name:"cyril", age: 34}, {name:"Tow", age: 3}]
```

So when you trying to get the index you must do like this:

```
dataset.findIndex(function(d){ return "cyril" == d.name})
//this will return 0 and for Tow return 1 and "Bow" will return -1
```

Thus in your code it will be like this:

```
d3.select("#tooltip")
    .style("left", xPosition + "px")
    .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
    .select("#share-value")
    .text(d)
    .select("#month-now")
    .text(function(d1){dataset.findIndex(function(d){ return YOUR_CONDITION})});
```

Hope this helps!